Error en Consulta Select Case en Access
La siguiente consulta en access:
SELECT INPUTPres25.,
CASE WHEN INPUTPres25.Servicio= 'NO' THEN 'No Disponible'
ELSE 'Disponible'
END AS 'SERVICIO FINAL'
FROM INPUTPres25;*
Me da el siguiente mensaje de error:
Error de sintaxis(falta operador) en la expresión de consulta 'CASE WHEN INPUTPres25.Servicio= 'NO' THEN 'No Disponible'
ELSE 'Disponible'
END'

Creo recordar que en el caso de MS Access no está disponible el CASE..WHEN, sólo cuando usas VBA.
Lo que sí puedes usar es el IFF con el que puedes conseguir algo equivalente; Prueba algo como esto:
SELECT INPUTPres25.*,
IIF(INPUTPres25.Servicio="NO", 'No disponible', 'Disponible') AS [SERVICIO FINAL]
FROM INPUTPres25

Y la otra alternativa es usar un SWITCH:
SELECT INPUTPres25.*,
  SWITCH(
  INPUTPres25.Servicio="NO", "No disponible",
  True, "Disponible"
  ) AS [SERVICIO FINAL]
FROM INPUTPres25

El resultado de ambos debería ser el mismo e igual a lo que pides.
